# changing devise route after edit user page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want my user to be able to go straight to the path subscriptions/new after landing on their edit user/update account page. can anyone help me as to how i would go about this. I have listed my routes below

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

   before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:name, :line1, :line2, :town, :county, :postcode, :password, :password_confrimation, :current_password)}
  end

 private
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    edit_user_registration_path(current_user) #basically whichever path you think meets your needs
  end
```

`routes.rb` file

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :subscriptions, only: [:new, :create, :show, :destroy]
  #gives standard routes

  get 'content/fruit'

  get 'content/veg'

  get 'content/mix'

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  namespace :admin do
  get 'dashboard/index'
  end

  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'devise/registrations'}
   # devise_for :users
   resources :products do 
   resources :orders, only: [:new, :create]
   #tells rails needs product id number
  end

  # get 'pages/payment'

  get 'home/about'

  get 'home/contact'

  get 'seller' => "products#seller"

  get 'sales' => "orders#sales"

  get 'static_pages/productlanding'

  get "content/veg"

  get "content/fruit"

  get "content/mix"

  get 'subscriptions/new'
```

Devise Registration Controller

```
class Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController

  def update
    set_flash_message :notice, :"message here" if is_flashing_format?
    session[:user_return_to] = new_subscription_path
    super  
  end
end
```

Edit form user

```
<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>


  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :avatar, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label'  %>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
    <div class="form-group">
      Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i>
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i>
    <%= f.password_field :current_password, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :line1 %>
    <%= f.text_field :line1, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :line2 %>
    <%= f.text_field :line2, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :town %>
    <%= f.text_field :town, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :county %>
    <%= f.text_field :county, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :postcode %>
    <%= f.text_field :postcode, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :organization %>
    <%= f.text_field :organization, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<h3>Cancel my account</h3>

<p>Unhappy? <%= button_to "cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger" %></p>

<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
```

Comment: You have write `redirect_to ...._path` after `update` in your method

Comment: When you mention "straight from edit/update", what do you mean? Do you want to redirect *after* action has been performed, or change the route itself?

Comment: yes i mean redirect after the action has been performed. Sorry quite new to rails..

Comment: nithin could you expand on your comment a bit i dont quite understand what you mean!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change path on this method [after_update_path_for(resource)](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L131)

```
class Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController

  ## other devise stuff

  protected

  def after_update_path_for(resource)
    new_subscription_path
  end

end
```

If you have multiple devise model you can try this

```
class Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController

  ## other devise stuff

  protected

  def after_update_path_for(resource)
    if resource.is_a?(DeviseModel1)
     new_subscription_path
    else
     other_path
    end
  end

end
```

Or you can put them into `application_controller.rb`

Comment: I tried the first suggestion as dont have multiple devise model but it still re directs to homepage?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override update action of devise registration controller for this.

```
class Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController

  def update
    set_flash_message :notice, :"message here" if is_flashing_format?
    session[:user_return_to] = new_subscription_path
    super  
  end
end
```

In your routes :

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'devise/registrations'}
```

There should be another controller `app/controllers/devise/registrations`. Controller code above.

If you want to make custom message then it come from `config/locales/en.yml`:

```
en:
  devise:
    registrations:
      destroyed: "my custom message." 
      updated: "my custom message"
```

Comment: how do i generate  devise registrations controller? I dont have one at all. Everything devise related i in my applications controller?

Comment: You can directly add to your app. In path I specified

Comment: thanks i did this as above but after the user clicks update on their edit profile page it still routes back to the homepage?

Comment: Where you put your registration controller ?

Comment: app/controllers/devise/registrations

Comment: Is registrations folder you created? If yes remove it and put controller in devise folder. Other than that everything looks good try put debugger in your new registration controller and see method properly calling or not

Comment: so the registrations controller should not be this route? I am a bit confused?    app/controllers/devise/registrations

Comment: No route should be the same. If you have another folder called registrations under devise then just remove that folder. Your registration controller should be in `app/controllers/devise`

Comment: i do have another folder called registrations under devise in my views but thats all...

Comment: No I am asking for controller.

Comment: theres no other folder under controller but still no joy im afraid

Comment: try put debugger in your registration controller update action and let me know if it's debugging code or not. Like it stops on debugger or not

Comment: sorry i am new to rails! I am not quite sure what you mean by debugger!